# Syntax error when using for loop in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop

I get this error from the code below.

```
Error:
**if names == inp1:
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax**  "^" points colon
```

I can't find the problem.
Code:

```
dic = {"John" : 12345,
   "Blake" : 456789,
   "Scarlett" : 124578,
   "Jake" : 852147,
   "Robert" : 963247895,
   "Jessica" : 4125036 }

for names in dic:
    inp1 = str(input("Enter your username: ")
    if names == inp1:
        inp2 = int(input("Enter your password: ")
        for pin in dic[names]:
            if inp2 == pin:
                print("*Access Granted*")
            else:
                print("*Access Denied")
    else:
        print("Wrong username")
```

Comment: uneven parentheses on previous line

Comment: `str(input("Enter your username: ")` close parentheses here and also on the next input.

Comment: ...and it the later too - both on lines `inp1...` and `inp2...`

Comment: inp1 = str(input("Enter your username: ")  less a right parenthesis

Comment: A few advices to avoid these issues: 1) when you open a parentheses, close it right away and *then* insert the code within the parentheses; 2) enable parenthesis matching in your editor; 3) enable a linter in your editor

Comment: Thanks for the help. Code doesn't work anyway. Every time it says Wrong Password.

Comment: Syntax and logic errors aside, this is not a good way to use a dictionary. Don't loop over all the keys to find the one that matches.

Comment: BTW, it's bad security to allow an attacker to test for valid user names like that, but I guess it's not a big deal for a toy program like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the if-else directly without for-loop for dictionary accessing.
The dictionary in python like Hash-map data structure in other language.

```
inp1 = input("Enter your username: ")
inp2 = int(input("Enter your password: "))

if inp1 in dic:
  if inp2 == dic[inp1]:
    print("*Access Granted*")
  else:
    print("*Access Denied")
else:
  print("Wrong username")
```

link: https://repl.it/repls/AutomaticHospitableJay

Comment: **1** Those `str` calls are redundant: `input` returns a string. **2** Instead of `if inp1 in dic.keys():` you can write `if inp1 in dic:`

Answer (score 0):

U left bracket in loop
ur corrected code:-

```
dic = {"John" : 12345,
   "Blake" : 456789,
   "Scarlett" : 124578,
   "Jake" : 852147,
   "Robert" : 963247895,
   "Jessica" : 4125036 }

for names in dic:
    inp1 = str(input("Enter your username: "))
    if names == inp1:
        inp2 = int(input("Enter your password: "))
        for pin in dic[names]:
            if inp2 == pin:
                print("*Access Granted*")
            else:
                print("*Access Denied")
    else:
        print("Wrong username")
```

Comment: I hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

```
closing bracket is missing in input statement and second loop is not required.Also str() parsing is not required. By defalut input returns type is string     
dic = {"John" : 12345,
       "Blake" : 456789,
       "Scarlett" : 124578,
       "Jake" : 852147,
       "Robert" : 963247895,
       "Jessica" : 4125036 }

    for names in dic:
        inp1 = str(input("Enter your username: "))
        if names == inp1:
            inp2 = int(input("Enter your password: "))
            if inp2 == dic[names]:
                print("*Access Granted*")
            else:
                print("*Access Denied")
        else:
            print("Wrong username")
```